# Which Eclipse version have I got installed?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I just installed the latest Eclipse from the [official download page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). I chose Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. Now, I'd like to install Pydev, which kindly asks me to use at least version 3.6.1. I promptly go to Help->About in Eclipse, and fail to see any version number which resembles 3.6.1. Instead, I'm getting this:

```
Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705
(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2000, 2010.  All rights reserved.
Visit http://eclipse.org/
```

So, how do I find out which actual version **number** I am running?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your concrete question, but I can confirm that Helios SR1 equals to 3.6.1. Was that Pydev installer message an error or just informal and could you just proceed?

Comment: @BalusC - I was just curious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click on Help -> About Eclipse, then click on the Eclipse icon for details.

See also this screenshot:

[image]

You most likely have 3.6.1 already, but what might be the problem is that you have an earlier build number.

Answer (score 2):

Helios contains Eclipse 3.6. [[Ref](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Helios_Plan)].

Helios SR1 contains Eclipse 3.6.1 [[Ref](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/sr1)]

Comment: and for older versions, refer [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Older_Versions_Of_Eclipse)